# Connect android xmlrpc to java server

Tags: java, android, xml-rpc

I used this library
[android xml rpc](https://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/)
 to call "sum" function in Java server, but it didn't work, i cannot call sum function

This is my android code: (I run it on real device)

```
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://192.168.1.57:8000/RPC2");
int sum = (Integer) client.call("sum", 2);
```

This is my server code:

```
public class JavaServer {

    private Integer sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("Attempting to start XML-RPC Server...");

            WebServer server = new WebServer(8000);

            XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = server.getXmlRpcServer();

            PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
            phm.addHandler("sample", JavaServer.class);
            xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);

            server.start();

            System.out.println("Started successfully.");
            System.out.println("Accepting requests. (Halt program to stop.)");
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("JavaServer: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public Integer sum(int x){
        sum += x;
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```